# probllem with turtlebot configuration

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can I configure upstart for turtlebot in ros fuerte?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39059/probllem-with-turtlebot-configuration/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/upstart there is a file called install.bash.

Use that as follows:

```
sudo ./install.bash <wireless interface>
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1